# Mysql capture meta_key as columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL view (data coming from joined Wordpress Tables) to capture form submission data.

The table description looks like:

```
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| post_id    | bigint(20) unsigned | YES  |     | 0       |       |
| field_id   | bigint(21)          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| meta_value | longtext            | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| key        | longtext            | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| label      | longtext            | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| user_id    | varchar(255)        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| course_id  | varchar(255)        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| post_date  | date                | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

The data deals with user submission of ratings for various courses that they took on our website.

Data looks like this:

```
+---------+----------------------------+-----------------------------------------
| post_id | meta_value                 | label          | user_id | post_date |
+---------+----------------------------+-----------------------------------------
|    1250 | 10                         | Question?      | NULL    | NULL      |
|    1250 |                            | Question?      | NULL    | NULL      |
|    1250 | 10                         | Question?      | NULL    | NULL      |
|    1250 |                            | Question?      | NULL    | NULL      |
|    1250 | 5                          | Question.      | NULL    | NULL      |
|    1250 | 5                          | Question.      | NULL    | NULL      |
|    1250 | 5                          | Question.      | NULL    | NULL      |
|    1250 | 5                          | Question.      | NULL    | NULL      |
|    1250 | email1@domain.org          | User           | 4       | NULL      |
|    1250 | X22-XXXX-ENG               | Course         | NULL    | 185       |
|    1251 | 10                         | Question?      | NULL    | NULL      |
|    1251 |                            | Question?      | NULL    | NULL      |
|    1251 | 10                         | Question?      | NULL    | NULL      |
|    1251 |                            | Question?      | NULL    | NULL      |
|    1251 | 5                          | Question.      | NULL    | NULL      |
|    1251 | 5                          | Question.      | NULL    | NULL      |
|    1251 | 5                          | Question.      | NULL    | NULL      |
|    1251 | 5                          | Question.      | NULL    | NULL      |
|    1251 | 5                          | Question.      | NULL    | NULL      |
|    1251 | email2@domain.org          | User           | 4       | NULL      |
|    1251 | X22-XXXX-ENG               | Course         | NULL    | 187       |
```

I want capture the submission data for each user so that I get the questions / User / Course in columns and the values in rows.

I can achieve the same for User and Course fields with the SQL:

```
select post_id
, max(case when label = 'Course' then meta_value end) AS course
, max(case when label = 'User' then meta_value end) AS user
, post_date
from lnd_wp_nps
group by post_id
order by post_id
```

I get the following output:

```
+---------+--------------+----------------------------+------------+
| post_id | course       | user                       | post_date  |
+---------+--------------+----------------------------+------------+
|    1250 | X22-XXX1-ENG | test_1@domain.org          | 2021-10-13 |
|    1251 | X22-XXX2-ENG | test_2@domain.org          | 2021-10-13 |
|    1252 | X22-XXX3-ENG | test_3@domain.org          | 2021-10-13 |
|    1253 | X22-XXX4-ENG | test_4@domain.org          | 2021-10-13 |
|    1259 | X22-XXX5-ENG | test_5@domain.com          | 2021-10-15 |
+---------+--------------+----------------------------+------------+
```

I want it to capture the questions as columns and the meta_value related to the questions as rows. Something like this:

[image]

How can I capture these dynamic questions as columns for each user?

> Note: I cannot hard code all these questions

I have tried : `max(case when label not in ('User Email', 'Course Shortcode') then label end) AS questions`

But it doesn't work, as it's giving me only ONE meta_values and the questions are not captured as columns.

Please let me know if I need to add anything else for more clarification.

Uploaded a sample Table in SQLFiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5e4751/1/0

Update:

Ran this query:

```
SELECT CONCAT( "select `post_id`,"
                ,"MAX(IF(`key_field` = 'course_shortcode' , `meta_value`,'')) AS `shortname`,"
                ," MAX(IF(`key_field` = 'user_email' , `meta_value`,'')) AS 'Email',"
        , GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT("MAX(IF(`key_field` = '",q.`key_field`,"' , `meta_value`,'')) AS '",q.key_field,"'\n") )
        , ", `post_date` FROM `wp_meta_value`
GROUP BY `post_id` ") INTO @query_wp_nps
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT `key_field`
    FROM `lnd_wp_nps`
    WHERE `key_field` NOT IN ('user_email', 'course_shortcode')
    ORDER BY LENGTH(key_field),`key_field` ASC ) q;
```

`prepare stmt from @query_wp_nps;`

Error:

```
MySQL [ja_etl]> prepare stmt from @query_wp_nps;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''dollars_with_sense_has_taught_me_mor, `post_date` FROM `wp_meta_value`
GROUP BY' at line 7
```

[image]

Updated Query:

```
SELECT CONCAT( "select `post_id`,"
                ,"MAX(IF(`key_field` = 'course_shortcode' , `meta_value`,'')) AS `shortname`,"
                ," MAX(IF(`key_field` = 'user_email' , `meta_value`,'')) AS 'Email',"
        , GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT("MAX(IF(`key_field` = '",q.`key_field`,"' , `meta_value`,'')) AS '",SUBSTR(q.key_field,1,64),"'\n") )
        , ", `post_date` FROM `wp_meta_value`
GROUP BY `post_id` ") INTO @query_wp_nps
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT `key_field`
    FROM `lnd_wp_nps`
    WHERE `key_field` NOT IN ('user_email', 'course_shortcode')) q;
```

But it still gives the error during prepare statement command:

[image]

```
select @query_wp_nps;

> | select `post_id`,MAX(IF(`key_field` = 'course_shortcode' ,
> `meta_value`,'')) AS `shortname`, MAX(IF(`key_field` = 'user_email' ,
> `meta_value`,'')) AS 'Email',MAX(IF(`key_field` =
> 'on_a_scale_where_1_is_the_least_and_10_is_the_most_likely_how_likely_are_you_to_recommend_ja_to_a_friend_or_family_member'
> , `meta_value`,'')) AS
> 'on_a_scale_where_1_is_the_least_and_10_is_the_most_likely_ho'
> ,MAX(IF(`key_field` =
> 'what_could_we_do_to_make_the_ja_experience_better' ,
> `meta_value`,'')) AS
> 'what_could_we_do_to_make_the_ja_experience_better'
> ,MAX(IF(`key_field` =
> 'on_a_scale_where_1_is_the_least_and_10_is_the_most_likely_how_likely_are_you_to_recommend_the_our_business_world_program_to_a_friend_or_family_member'
> , `meta_value`,'')) AS
> 'on_a_scale_where_1_is_the_least_and_10_is_the_most_likely_ho'
> ,MAX(IF(`key_field` =
> 'what_could_we_do_to_make_our_business_world_better' ,
> `meta_value`,'')) AS
> 'what_could_we_do_to_make_our_business_world_better'
> ,MAX(IF(`key_field` =
> 'our_business_world_has_taught_me_more_about_how_businesses_start_and_operate'
> , `meta_value`,'')) AS
> 'our_business_world_has_taught_me_more_about_how_businesses_s'
> ,MAX(IF(`key_field` = 'our_business_world_has_, `post_date` FROM
> `wp_meta_value` GROUP BY `post_id`  |

MySQL [ja_etl]> prepare stmt from @query_wp_nps;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''our_business_world_has_, `post_date` FROM `wp_meta_value`
GROUP BY `post_id`' at line 6
```

Comment: can you pls post your table in http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: @BerndBuffen here is the sqlfiddle link:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5e4751/1/0

Comment: thanks, how do you generate the content from column "CURSE" with C!,..C4.
Today i will send you a query for the pivot table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a MySQL prepared Statement to generate a dynamic query and then execute this like:

```
SELECT CONCAT( "select `post_id`,"
                ,"MAX(IF(`label` = 'Course' , `meta_value`,'')) AS `course_id`,"
                ," MAX(IF(`label` = 'User' , `meta_value`,'')) AS 'Email',"
        , GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT("MAX(IF(`label` = '",q.`label`,"' , `meta_value`,'')) AS '",SUBSTR(q.label,1,64),"'\n") )
        , ", `post_date` FROM `wp_meta_value`
GROUP BY `post_id` ") INTO @myquery
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT `label`
    FROM `wp_meta_value`
    WHERE `label` NOT IN ('User','Course','User Email', 'Course Shortcode')
    ORDER BY LENGTH(label),`label` ASC ) q;
    
SELECT @myquery; ## only to see the generated query
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE @myquery;
```

**sample generate query**

```
MariaDB [pivot]> SELECT CONCAT( "select `post_id`,"
    ->  ,"MAX(IF(`label` = 'Course' , `meta_value`,'')) AS `course_id`,"
    ->  ," MAX(IF(`label` = 'User' , `meta_value`,'')) AS 'Email',"
    ->  , GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT("MAX(IF(`label` = '",q.`label`,"' , `meta_value`,'')) AS '",q.label,"'\n") )
    -> , ", `post_date` FROM `wp_meta_value`
    "> GROUP BY `post_id` ") INTO @myquery
    -> FROM (
    -> SELECT DISTINCT `label`
    -> FROM `wp_meta_value`
    -> WHERE `label` NOT IN ('User','Course','User Email', 'Course Shortcode')
    -> ORDER BY LENGTH(label),`label` ASC ) q;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.10 sec)

MariaDB [pivot]>
```

**show the generated query**

```
MariaDB [pivot]> SELECT @myquery;
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| @myquery                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| select `post_id`,MAX(IF(`label` = 'Course' , `meta_value`,'')) AS `course_id`, MAX(IF(`label` = 'User' , `meta_value`,'')) AS 'Email',MAX(IF(`label` = 'Question1' , `meta_value`,'')) AS 'Question1'
,MAX(IF(`label` = 'Question2' , `meta_value`,'')) AS 'Question2'
,MAX(IF(`label` = 'Question3' , `meta_value`,'')) AS 'Question3'
,MAX(IF(`label` = 'Question4' , `meta_value`,'')) AS 'Question4'
,MAX(IF(`label` = 'Question5' , `meta_value`,'')) AS 'Question5'
,MAX(IF(`label` = 'Question6' , `meta_value`,'')) AS 'Question6'
,MAX(IF(`label` = 'Question7' , `meta_value`,'')) AS 'Question7'
,MAX(IF(`label` = 'Question8' , `meta_value`,'')) AS 'Question8'
,MAX(IF(`label` = 'Question9' , `meta_value`,'')) AS 'Question9'
,MAX(IF(`label` = 'Question10' , `meta_value`,'')) AS 'Question10'
, `post_date` FROM `wp_meta_value`
GROUP BY `post_id`  |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**execute the query**

```
MariaDB [pivot]> EXECUTE IMMEDIATE @myquery;
+---------+--------------+-------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+
| post_id | course_id    | Email             | Question1 | Question2 | Question3 | Question4 | Question5 | Question6 | Question7 | Question8 | Question9 | Question10 | post_date  |
+---------+--------------+-------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+
|    1250 | X22-XXXX-ENG | email1@domain.org | 10        | 7         | 8         |           |           |           |           |           |           |            | 2021-10-13 |
|    1251 | X23-XXXX-ENG | email3@domain.org |           |           |           | 9         | 4         | 7         |           |           |           |            | 2021-10-13 |
|    1252 | X24-XXXX-ENG | email3@domain.org |           |           |           |           |           |           | 5         | 9         | 8         | 6          | 2021-10-13 |
+---------+--------------+-------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [pivot]>
```

Comment: The solution works with the example data you have used. It is perfect ! But it fails when I am using with actual data.

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''dollars_with_sense_has_taught_me_mor, `post_date` FROM `wp_meta_value`
GROUP BY' at line 7`

I have checked everything and there are no data issues.

Comment: Show me the error and send sqlfiddle some data

Comment: Is the error in the first query or by the eyexution of the generated sql.

Comment: Can you me send the output from select @myquery

Comment: I have updated my Post with the Prepared Statement and Error. Let me know if you need anything else

Comment: yes, pls show the output from **SELECT @query_wp_nps;** before you run prepare and if possible give me a small table with your name and field and sample data

Comment: I have found the error :-) The max fieldname length is 64 in MySQL. So some name are longer in your case. change the group_concat line to: **GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT("MAX(IF(`label` = '",q.`label`,"' , `meta_value`,'')) AS '",SUBSTR(q.label,1,64),"'\n") )** . I have also change it in my answer

Comment: I have added the ```GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT("MAX(IF(`key_field` = '",q.`key_field`,"' , `meta_value`,'')) AS '",SUBSTR(q.key_field,1,64),"'\n") )```in the code,

Updated my Post with it. Still it's not able to capture everything and throwing error when running prepared statement. I have uploaded the screenshot of the output of the select query.

Comment: post it as text, then can i copy it

Comment: Edited my post with the select result as text and the error as text.

Comment: you have destroy this line(s) **,MAX(IF(`key_field` = 'our_business_world_has_, `post_date` FROM** . change it to **,MAX(IF(`key_field` = 'our_business_world_has_, `post_date` ,'')) FROM**

Comment: ```,MAX(IF(`key_field` = 'our_business_world_has_, `post_date` ```
This is the output from SELECT @myquery

How can I edit this? This is generated dynamically I think?

Comment: pls, send me the first query that wll generate the the@.... then i will fix it for you

Comment: you can also call me +49 2163 9879851

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238285/discussion-between-aki2all-and-bernd-buffen).