# SQL count distinct column with row value

Tags: mysql

I have the table `tbl_rating` which contains survey results with the following structure:

```
| office_name | rating      |
|-------------|-------------|
| Office1     | Satisfied   |
| Office3     | Unsatisfied |
| Office2     | Neutral     |
| Office1     | Satisfied   |
```

I'm having trouble having my query display all `DISTINCT` values of the `office_name` column with the total number of the same value from the `rating` column.

The result from the query I am looking for is the following:

```
| office_name | Satisfied | Neutral | Unsatisfied |
|-------------|-----------|---------|-------------|
| Office1     | 2         | 0       | 0           |
| Office2     | 0         | 1       | 0           |
| Office3     | 0         | 0       | 1           |
```

this is query that i'm working with at the moment. it works for counting total number of rating of the declared value, but does gives me an error when I tried to display the result of the array using **DISTINCT office**

```
$office = $db->query("SELECT DISTINCT office
(SELECT COUNT(rating) FROM tbl_result WHERE rating='Satisfied') AS S,
(SELECT COUNT(rating) FROM tbl_result WHERE rating='Neutral') AS N,
(SELECT COUNT(rating) FROM tbl_result WHERE rating='Unsatisfied') AS U");
```

Comment: see this if can help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69597435/mysql-capture-meta-key-as-columns/69602090?noredirect=1#comment123058541_69602090

Comment: Can you please include your current attempt at doing this with the query you have written?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
  office_name,
  SUM(IF(rating = 'Satisfied', 1, 0)) AS Satisfied,
  SUM(IF(rating = 'Neutral', 1, 0)) AS Neutral,
  SUM(IF(rating = 'Unsatisfied', 1, 0)) AS Unsatisfied
FROM
  tbl_rating
GROUP BY
  office_name
```

Edited (thanks to *sticky bit* for his remarks):

- removed DISTINCT clause
- changed double quotes around strings to single quotes

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/358d5f/1)

Comment: The `DISTINCT` is superfluous.

Comment: Side note: Don't get used to use double quotes for string or date literals. Yes, sadly MySQL accepts that, but in SQL double quotes are usually for identifiers, such as column names. Should you ever use another DBMS (or future MySQL versions become more sane about this) you'll likely get an "invalid object name" error. Always use single quotes for string or date literals.

Comment: And you don't even need the `IF()` as in MySQL Boolean expressions are automatically casted to `0` or `1` in numeric context.

Comment: yes, this will work, but only for 3 columns and 3 hard coded values, if there more values or other values you must change the query. i vote up

Comment: Thanks a lot, very appreciated! (I will leave the IF clause as I think it is more readable)

Comment: It works. it gave me the result i needed. for a newbie who still studying SQL, i was running in circles with the SELECT DISTINCT and COUNT statement. i never realized it could be solved by GROUP BY and SUM. i learned something. thank you so much